# Display: none on container element breaks jquery absolute positioning calculation childrens child elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<a href="" id="show_link">Show</a><div id="container">
<form class="form">
    <a href="" class="align_middle">Link1</a>
</form>
<form class="form">
    <a href="" class="align_middle">Link2</a>
</form>
<form class="form">
    <a href="" class="align_middle">Link3</a>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var align_middle = function(element) {

    var sidePadding = 20;

    $(element).css("position", "static");
    $(element).css("float", "left");
    $(element).css("width", "auto");

    var width = $(element).width();
    var parentWidth = $(element).parent().width();

    width = Math.min(width, parentWidth - sidePadding*2);
    $(element).css("width", width);

    var height = $(element).height();
    var parentHeight = $(element).parent().height();
    var top = (parentHeight - height)/2;
    var left = (parentWidth - width)/2;

    $(element).css("position", "absolute");
    $(element).css("left", left + "px");
    $(element).css("top", top + "px");

    $(element).css("float", "");
};

$(document).ready(function(){

    var elements = $(".align_middle");

    $.each(elements, function(key,value){
            align_middle(value);
    });

    $(elements).bind("DOMNodeInserted",function(){
            align_middle(this);
    });


    $("#show_link").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $("div#container").toggle();
    });

});
```

CSS:

```
.form {
    position: relative;
    border-color: brown;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: dotted;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div#container{
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

I want to hide the div#container with the css property display: none; so it's hidden on page load, but it breaks the align_middle function.

When I hide the elements via a $.get callback function it's working great. (The toggle link work as well.)

Why does it behave like this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7PELA/3/

Comment: you are literally hiding the element, how do you expect it to behave? can you riddle a bit more?

Comment: Maybe I should update the fiddle to show how it breaks? If I put display: none; in the css for div#container the Link1, Link2 and Link3 isn't centered anymore..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS `display:none;` property from a DOM perspective completely removes or does not process the element in the browser so the jQuery is not able to correctly calculate what it needs to. Rather use the Visibility property in CSS and set it to hidden.

**Updated HTML:**

```
<a href="" id="show_link">Show</a>
<div id="container" class="hide">
    <form class="form">
        <a href="" class="align_middle">Link1</a>
    </form>
    <form class="form">
        <a href="" class="align_middle">Link2</a>
    </form>
    <form class="form">
        <a href="" class="align_middle">Link3</a>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Updated CSS:**

```
.form
{
position:relative;
border-color:brown;
border-width:3px;
border-style:dotted;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
float:left;
margin-left:10px;
overflow:hidden;
}

div#container
{
overflow:auto;
margin-top:10px;
}

.hide {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

**Updated jQuery:**

```
var align_middle = function(element){

    var sidePadding = 20;

    $(element).css("position", "static");
    $(element).css("float", "left");
    $(element).css("width", "auto");

    var width = $(element).width();
    var parentWidth = $(element).parent().width();

    width = Math.min(width, parentWidth - sidePadding*2);
    $(element).css("width", width);

    var height = $(element).height();
    var parentHeight = $(element).parent().height();
    var top = (parentHeight - height)/2;
    var left = (parentWidth - width)/2;

    $(element).css("position", "absolute");
    $(element).css("left", left + "px");
    $(element).css("top", top + "px");

    $(element).css("float", "");

};

$(document).ready(function(){

    var elements = $(".align_middle");

    $.each(elements, function(key,value){

        align_middle(value);

    });

    $(elements).bind("DOMNodeInserted",function(){
        align_middle(this);
    });


    $("#show_link").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("div#container").toggleClass('hide');
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you man, it works great and also explains the reason behind.

Answer (score 1):

how about this? http://jsfiddle.net/7PELA/4/

just needs a little `$("#show_link").trigger('click');` after the "click toggle" function no need to set `display:none`

Comment: It actually works. :) Why doesn't it work to use display:hidden; ?

Comment: honestly I have no idea! :) never seen or had to look for such problem!

Comment: See Matts answer. Thanks anyway. :)